# extended data table dynamic result rich faces

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

```
<h:form>


<h:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="top , top">
    <rich:extendedDataTable
        value="#{contentBean.questions}" var="cap" id="table"
        selectionMode="single"
        tableState="#{contentBean.qtablestate}"
        selection="#{contentBean.s}">
        <rich:column  id="col_1">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Quistioneer" id="flag"/>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{cap.QUserid.fname}" id="cap_state_flag"/>
        </rich:column>
        <rich:column id="col_2" width="170px">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Question" id="state_name"/>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{cap.questionValue}" id="cap_state"/>
        </rich:column>
        <rich:column id="col_3" width="170px">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Date asked" id="state_capital"/>
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{cap.QDate}" id="cap_name"/>
        </rich:column>

        <a4j:ajax execute="@form" event="selectionchange" listener="#{contentBean.onclick(cap.qid)}" 
                  render="selectiontable"/>
    </rich:extendedDataTable>
    <h:panelGroup layout="block" style="width:400px">
         <rich:panel>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Currently selected rows:" />
            </f:facet>
            <rich:dataTable value="#{contentBean.ansList}"
                var="sel" id="selectiontable">
                <rich:column>
                    <h:outputText value="#{sel.AUserid.fname}" />
                </rich:column>
                <rich:column>
                    <h:outputText value="#{sel.ansValue}" />
                </rich:column>
                <rich:column>
                    <h:outputText value="#{sel.ansDate}" />
                </rich:column>
            </rich:dataTable>
        </rich:panel>
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:panelGrid>

  </h:form>
```

i wanted to show results on the selected panel from the data table by sending the cap.userid (data variable of list ) to the backing bean  from the column  selected in the extended data table (i need to call the method onclick to get the table rows from backing session to show on Second panel)
My problem is listner is calling function on select but i was not able to send that row data
please help how can i do that

Answer (score 1):

You can get the selection form your table selection:

```
 <rich:extendedDataTable
    ...
    selection="#{contentBean.selection}">
```

and take that in backend side.

```
for(Object objId:getSelection()){
```

The objId will be the id of your data.